# Invoking a function in the UI from a different thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I haven't done this in a while but I think I remember it correctly - in form1 class I have this

```
Public Sub print(s As String)
    TextBox1.Text = s & vbNewLine & TextBox1.Text
End Sub
Public Delegate Sub printDelDef(s As String)
Public printDel As New printDelDef(AddressOf print)
```

and in my threads worker sub I have this

```
    Form1.BeginInvoke(Form1.printDel, "Started work on " & Name & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString)
```

The thread is created in the class definition of the worker object like this:

```
Public t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Work)
```

I know that this combination has worked for me before, but this time I'm getting an error "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."

I don't know what that means but I do know that form1 has a method called "IsHandleCreated" so I thought maybe the invocation is being called too soon or something so I tried to wait for "form1.IsHandleCreated = true" but that never happens

Comment: Where are you starting your thread? Sounds like it is before Form1 is done initializing.

Comment: the worker objects are created in a sub triggered by form1.shown but I just tested it out to be sure, even if I create one with a button press I still get the same error.

Comment: Is `Form1` a reference to your actual instance of the form1 class, or is the `Form1.BeginInvoke` call using the default instance of the `Form1` class, which may not be the same thing?  How is `Form1` created/shown?

Comment: Form1 refers to the actual instance, its created by default when the program starts.

Comment: Another weird thing is that IsHandleCreated is always false when viewed from any of the worker threads and true when viewed from the main thread (before the workers even start)

Comment: The form instance is `Me` not the form name if referred to in the class itself.

Comment: I was just going to say to try `Me.BeginInvoke` instead of `Form1.BeginInvoke`, assuming this code is in the form.

Comment: but I'm calling it from outside the form1 class definition

Comment: I just tried directly reading and modifying form1.text from a the worker thread. It red correctly and upon modifying I didn't get a cross thread exception(which I should have) and also nothing changed on the window. This is so strange.

Comment: Ok, catching on to something. I added a shared member to form1 called "inst" and in the shown event assigned inst = me. Now when calling the delegate through form1.inst... it works correctly. So basically, for whatever reason form1 is not referring to the instance of the window after all. IIRC though, it used to, why would it be different?